# Parallel stream after collection update

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, java-stream

I make code compatible with OpenJDk8 and noticed that sometimes following snippets throws ConcurrentModificationException.

Code is executed in one thread.

```
list = new ArrayList<>();

list.addAll(newElements);
list.stream().parallel().forEach(o -> {});
```

Exception is thrown by ForkJoin when stream threads split the list between them selves.
After a moment I thought that it is reasonable behavior by default (not synchronized, simple collection) stream threads are not new and they used from pool (they could see list in inconsistent state), but copying collection before iterating would not look nice.

I haven't found a bug regarding this, so I ask the question what Java memory model thinks about this case?

BTW to file OJDK bug you have to be a developer.

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:735)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:160)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:233)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:583)
    at scheduler.JobScheduleUpdater.fetchJobSchedules(JobScheduleUpdater.java:118)
    at scheduler.JobScheduleUpdater.processOneUpdate(JobScheduleUpdater.java:102)
    at 
scheduler.JobScheduleUpdater.execute(JobScheduleUpdater.java:81)
    at scheduler.JobScheduleUpdater$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$ccd35a20.CGLIB$execute$11(<generated>)
    at scheduler.JobScheduleUpdater$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$ccd35a20$$FastClassByMockitoWithCGLIB$$bf9de679.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:216)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.repackaged.DelegatingMockitoMethodProxy.invokeSuper(DelegatingMockitoMethodProxy.java:20)
    at org.mockito.internal.invocation.realmethod.DefaultRealMethod.invoke(DefaultRealMethod.java:21)
    at org.mockito.internal.invocation.realmethod.CleanTraceRealMethod.invoke(CleanTraceRealMethod.java:30)
    at org.mockito.internal.invocation.InvocationImpl.callRealMethod(InvocationImpl.java:112)
    at org.mockito.internal.stubbing.answers.CallsRealMethods.answer(CallsRealMethods.java:41)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.MockHandlerImpl.handle(MockHandlerImpl.java:93)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.NullResultGuardian.handle(NullResultGuardian.java:29)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.InvocationNotifierHandler.handle(InvocationNotifierHandler.java:38)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.repackaged.MethodInterceptorFilter.intercept(MethodInterceptorFilter.java:60)
    at scheduler.JobScheduleUpdater$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$ccd35a20.execute(<generated>)
    at commons.util.service.ShutdownCapableThread.run(ShutdownCapableThread.java:74)
    at scheduler.JobScheduleUpdater$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$ccd35a20.CGLIB$run$15(<generated>)
    at scheduler.JobScheduleUpdater$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$ccd35a20$$FastClassByMockitoWithCGLIB$$bf9de679.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:216)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.repackaged.DelegatingMockitoMethodProxy.invokeSuper(DelegatingMockitoMethodProxy.java:20)
    at org.mockito.internal.invocation.realmethod.DefaultRealMethod.invoke(DefaultRealMethod.java:21)
    at org.mockito.internal.invocation.realmethod.CleanTraceRealMethod.invoke(CleanTraceRealMethod.java:30)
    at org.mockito.internal.invocation.InvocationImpl.callRealMethod(InvocationImpl.java:112)
    at org.mockito.internal.stubbing.answers.CallsRealMethods.answer(CallsRealMethods.java:41)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.MockHandlerImpl.handle(MockHandlerImpl.java:93)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.NullResultGuardian.handle(NullResultGuardian.java:29)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.InvocationNotifierHandler.handle(InvocationNotifierHandler.java:38)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.repackaged.MethodInterceptorFilter.intercept(MethodInterceptorFilter.java:60)
    at scheduler.JobScheduleUpdater$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$ccd35a20.run(<generated>)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1388)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute(ForEachOps.java:291)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:731)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

Comment: Is that your implemented code above? That would throw a compiler error.

Comment: This looks weird. [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please? Also if we need to run the example 50 times to see the error (`for` loops exist).

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Tried with different lists from 1 to 300 000 elements.

Comment: @Holger If the `PrintStream` doesn’t lock the system resource used to access the console. Having researched further though I realise this was a useless assumption

Comment: @MTCoster then, you might get problems with the `PrintStream` and its internally used resources, but not with an unrelated `ArrayList`  outside of it.

Comment: It is not about foreach body. It is 100% thread safe. The example is good. Stack trace from real exception. It is a thread safe question. So if somebody cannot reproduce the bug doesn't mean the code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The code runs fine in my editor. The `ConcurrentModificationException` triggers when you're modifying something you're iterating on. Without seeing all of your code I don't think I can relieve the problem.

An example of `ConcurrentModificationException` is:

```
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();

integers.add(12);
integers.add(11);
integers.add(1);



for (Integer integer : integers) {
   integers.remove(1);
}
```

A resource on how to solve your problem can be found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-concurrentmodificationexception).

Comment: It’s not really answering the question.

Comment: the code iterates collection after modification, but in other threads.